# Test connectivity of a Interface

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, ethernet-port, gsm

I have a raspberry Pi with three interfaces `eth0` (Ethernet), `wlan0` (WiFi), and `wwan0` (via a GSM modem)

1. How can I test if an Internet connection is available via a certain interface? e.g. is my GSM(`wwan0`) modem connected to the Internet?
2. If I attempt to run `ping www.google.com` - How do I know what interface is being used?

Comment: Hi there. It looks as if your question would be better suited on a different Stack Exchange site as it is more related to general Linux operation, rather than Raspberry Pi specifics. If you like I can migrate this question to a relevant place?

Comment: Good question though - [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) may be ideal for it.

Comment: @Morgan - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158901/test-connectivity-of-a-interface